# Нужна ли инстанциация класса без вызова функции шаблона?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

```
#include <type_traits>


template<typename T>
struct A {
    static_assert(!std::is_same_v<int, T>);
};

template<typename T>
struct B {
    void foo() {
        A<int>{};
    }
};


int main() {

}
```

Почему эта программа компилируется gcc и msvc ([1](https://godbolt.org/z/jXsBVl) и [2](https://godbolt.org/z/vKFvQj)), но не компилируется clang ([3](https://godbolt.org/z/YQE3bz))? Должна ли она компилироваться в соответствии со стандартом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Формально - Clang неправ, код должен компилироваться. Так как `foo` нигде не используется, она не должна инстантинироваться.

Следовательно, `A<int>` тоже не должен инстантинироваться, и `static_assert` не должен срабатывать.

---

Но вообще, по духу стандарта код должен быть ill-formed, no diagnostic required (что означало бы, что код невалиден, и что все три компилятора соответствуют стандарту) из-за вот этого раздела:

> #### [[temp.res]/8.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.1)
>
> <sup>8</sup> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation. [ Note: Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template to be checked in this way. — end note ] **The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:**
>
> <sup>(8.1)</sup> — **no valid specialization can be generated for a template** or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated, or
>
> ...

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

То есть если код в шаблоне некорректен для абсолютно всех возможных наборов шаблонных аргументов, то программа невалидна (но сообщение об ошибке не гарантируется).

`foo` невалидна для всех `T`, но так как сама `foo()` - не шаблон, к ней этот раздел не применяется.

Почему я говорю "по духу стандарта"?

Существует:

> #### [CWG issue 1253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1253): Generic non-template members
>
> **Section**: 17.8  [temp.spec]     **Status**: drafting     **Submitter**: Nikolay Ivchenkov     **Date**: 2011-03-06
>
> Many statements in the Standard apply only to templates, for example,
>   17.7 [temp.res] paragraph 8:
>
> > If no valid specialization can be generated for a template definition,
> >     and that template is not instantiated, the template definition is
> >     ill-formed, no diagnostic required.
>
> This clearly should apply to non-template member functions of class
>   templates, not just to templates per se. Terminology should be
>   established to refer to these generic entities that are not actually
>   templates.

<sup>(Спасибо [@StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53693349/2752075).)</sup>

Которая как раз утверждает, что разделы вроде `[temp.res]/8.1` должны применяться не только к шаблонам, но и нешаблонным членам шаблонных классов и т. п.

Судя по

> **Status**: drafting

Комитет согласен, что это нужно исправить, но с конкретными изменениями в текст стандарта по этой теме они пока не определились.

Comment: А почему "no valid specialization can be generated for a template"? Тут же только для int неверно

Comment: @cppquestions Речь не про `A`, а про `foo()`.

Comment: Так ведь функция нешаблонная и от `T` не зависит

Comment: @cppquestions Вы правы, обновил.

Comment: На конец 2022 года уже статус "open" — https://wg21.link/cwg1253, т.е. "the working group has not yet formed an opinion on the issue".

Answer (score 3):

Нет, не должна. В таком случае (определение структуры) нужна обязательная инстанциация. Однако стандарт разрешает не диагностировать подобную ошибку, если вызова не произошло (т.к. это потенциально замедляет компиляцию). Так что все правы, но clang более строг, как обычно.